# what is a pythonic way to get the number of times list1[i] < list2[i] and vise versa

Tags: python

I have two lists with values, the expected result is a tuple `(a,b)` where `a` is the number of i values which `list1[i] < list2[i]`, and `b` is the number of i values where `list1[i] > list2[i]` (equalities are not counted at all).

I have this solution, and it works perfectly:

```
x = (0,0)
for i in range(len(J48)):
    if J48[i] < useAllAttributes7NN[i]:
      x = (x[0]+1,x[1])
    elif J48[i] > useAllAttributes7NN[i]:
        x = (x[0], x[1]+1)
```

However, I am trying to improve my python skills, and it seems very non-pythonic way to achieve it.

**What is a pythonic way to achieve the same result?**

**FYI**, this is done to achieve the required input for [`binom_test()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html) that tries to prove two algorithms are not statistically identical.

I don't believe this information has any additional value to the specific question though.

Comment: Can it be assumed that `set(list1) == set(list2)`?

Comment: And equal values should just be ignored?

Comment: equal values are ignored I don't care about them, `set(list1) != set(list2)`, just the sizes are the same. These are double values representing accuracy of 2 algorithms, that should be compared using binomical test.

Comment: This does the trick: `x=(sum(1 for i in xrange(len(J48)) if J48[i] < useAllAttributes7NN[i]), sum(1 for i in xrange(len(J48)) if J48[i] > useAllAttributes7NN[i]))`.

Comment: another short version: `tmp=collections.Counter(itertools.imap(cmp, J48, useAllAttributes7NN)); x=(tmp[-1], tmp[1])`.

Comment: @hochi Again, it's worth noting that `cmp()` doesn't exist in 3.x.

Comment: Yes, I know ... the question isn't tagged as Python 3.x :P but anyways it'd be easy to insert a lambda expression then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to build a set of scores and then add them up.

```
scores = [ (a < b, a > b) for (a, b) in zip(J48, useAllAttributes7nn) ]
x = (sum( a for (a, _) in scores ), sum( b for (_, b) in scores ))

// Or, as per @agf's suggestion (though I prefer comprehensions to map)...
x = [ sum(s) for s in zip(*scores) ]
```

Another is to zip them once then count scores separately:

```
zipped = zip(J48, useAllAttributes7nn)
x = (sum( a < b for (a, b) in zipped ), sum( a > b for (a, b) in zipped ))
```

Note that this doesn't work in Python 3 (thanks @Darthfett).

Comment: You should be zipping again in the second line

Comment: @agf: Sorry, I don't get your drift.

Comment: Your first solution is probably the neatest way I can think of on such short notice.

Comment: `x = map(sum, zip(*scores))` is what your first version is doing on the second line.

Comment: In python 3.x, `zip` is a generator, which means you will have to zip it twice, use a list, or use `itertools.tee`.

Comment: The second is actually what I had in mind when reading my code and realizing it is not pythonic. +1, definetly accept candidate. thanks.

Comment: @Darthfett Indeed, in 3.x this will produce [..., 0] for all input. Easily fixed, however.

Comment: @agf: Nice suggestion. It never occurred to me you could transpose that way.

Comment: @Darthfett: Yikes! There's a well-covered trap for migrators.

Comment: The edit `x = [ sum(s) for s in zip(*scores) ]` is giving a list, not a tuple, same with `map()`. Is it python version issue?

Comment: @amit That is what it should be. It shouldn't really matter between tuple and list in most cases, but you can simply wrap it in `tuple()` if you want a tuple.

Comment: This solution is based in the fact that x<y equals 1 if true and 0 if flase, which intuitivily is dangerous since the python implementation running the code could decide to consider True as 2 for example. It's better to be explicit in this cases, so i suggest: `sum(1 for (a,b) in zipped if a < b)`

Comment: @jgomo3: Relational expressions evaluate to False or True, which are [explicitly defined](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values) as equivalent to 0 or 1, respectively, in numeric contexts.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the sake of fun, solving this problem using complex numbers. Though not Pythonic but quite mathematical :-)

Just think this problem as plotting the result on a two dimensional complex space

```
result=sum((x < y) + (x > y)*1j for x,y  in zip(list1,list2))
(result.real,result.imag)
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's a horrible abuse, and yet a lovely hack. Edit: Just to clarify, as cool as this is, it's not readable, and I wouldn't use it in the real world.

Comment: This is fun! I assume it is not efficient, but I am using it for off-line code, so it's fine. +1.

Comment: @Lattyware I think It's readable if 2 lines of comment precede the code explaining the math

Comment: Readable was probably the wrong thing there, misleading is more the right term. Using complex numbers imply that they have a purpose.

Comment: @Lattyware: Well complex number's serve a purpose to classify items in two dimensional plane and this problem is what we are trying to do. Trying to classify the items into two different groups and complex numbers may serve quite a fruitful purpose here. Nevertheless I would seldom use it myself unless I am solving a problem in Physics where a similar classification would be required. But saying this I will differ from you saying its an abuse :-)

Comment: @amit: `I assume it is not efficient`, and do you have a reason to think so? Though I didn;t profile it but still it may not be that inefficient

Comment: @Abhijit: I am basing it on nothing actually, just a hunch.. doesn't matter anyway though. I do agree that reducing the problem into 2-dimendional is a nice approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

x = [0, 0, 0]
for a, b in itertools.izip(J48, useAllAttributes7NN):
    x[cmp(a, b)] += 1
```

and then take just `x[0]` and `x[2]`, because `x[1]` counts the equalities.

Another way (has to parse the lists twice):

```
first = sum(1 for a, b in itertools.izip(J48, useAllAttributes7NN) if a > b)
second = sum(1 for a, b in itertools.izip(J48, useAllAttributes7NN) if a < b)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `cmp()` doesn't exist in Python 3.x

Comment: I am not using 3.x, so it is fine to me, but the result is in 1,2 and not 0,1. other then it, it works. +1. I'll look for other answers and accept the one that seems most pythonic later on.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is:

```
list1 = range(10)
list2 = reversed(range(10))
x = [0, 0]
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    x[0] += 1 if a < b else 0
    x[1] += 1 if a > b else 0
x = tuple(x)
```

Giving us:

```
(5, 5)
```

[`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#zip) is the best way to iterate over two lists at once. If you are using Python 2.x, you might want to use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for performance reasons (it's lazy like Python 3.x's `zip()`.

It's also easier to work on a list until you stop changing it, as a list is mutable.

## Edit:

A Python 3-compatible version of the versions that use `cmp`:

```
def add_tuples(*args):
   return tuple(sum(z) for z in zip(*args))

add_tuples(*[(1, 0) if a < b else ((0, 1) if a > b else (0, 0)) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)])
```

Comment: @Lattyware: The last solution is now lacking readability. I had a hard time reading through all the 0s and 1s

Comment: @Abhijit I completely agree, it's purely that `(1, 0) if a < b else ((0, 1) if a > b else (0, 0))` is needed to replace the used of `cmp()` in 3.x - I don't think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about:

```
import itertools
def func(list1, list2):
    x,y = 0,0
    for (a,b) in itertools.izip(list1, list2):
      if a > b:
        x += 1
      elif a < b:
        y += 1
    print x,y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 3, 7, 15, 22, 27]
list2 = [2, 5, 10, 12, 20, 30]

x = 0
y = 0 
for index, value in enumerate(list1):
    if value < list2[index]:
        x += 1
    elif value > list2[index]:
        y += 1

print (x, y)
```

Comment: This doesn't follow what the asker wanted - that is, equal values should not increment either option. Enumerate is also a terrible way to loop over two lists.